# PostgreSQL: Invalid endian flag value encountered

Tags: java, postgresql, geospatial

I'm trying to set up a PostreSQL table with some geospatial data in it and make some spatial queries. But I'm getting "Invalid endian flag value encountered" error.
I've been looking for a solution on the internet, but none has done the job so far. Running out of ideas. Need help.

This is the scenario

The entity class:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon;

@Entity
public class PontodeInteresse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String descricao;

    private Point ponto;

    private LineString linha;

    private Geometry geometry;

    private Polygon poligono;

    /* Getters and setters */
```

I can insert a Polygon from code. Everything seems to be fine:

```
public void criarGeometry () {
    PontodeInteresse ponto = new PontodeInteresse();

    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

    LinearRing shell = gf.createLinearRing(new Coordinate[] {
                                new Coordinate(-43.5552982, -22.8839067), new Coordinate(-43.5556591, -22.8838402),
                                new Coordinate(-43.5554786, -22.8829425), new Coordinate(-43.5555869, -22.8824438),
                                new Coordinate(-43.5552982, -22.8839067)});
    LinearRing[] holes = new LinearRing[0];
    Polygon polygon = gf.createPolygon(shell, holes);        
    ponto.setGeometry(polygon);
    colocar(ponto);
}
```

But, when I try to run a simple geospatial query from the method testar() (below), I get the "Invalid endian flag value encountered" error. 
    I have already tried to use @Column and set the geo types, but got no  luck. 
    The very same error happens if I try to run this  query from PgAdmin:

SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeomFromWKB(geometry)) from pontodeinteresse;

```
   public void testar() {
        try {
            GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
            Point pontoDentro = gf.createPoint( new Coordinate(-43.5658, -22.8722) );
            PontodeInteresse bairro = null;
            bairro = (PontodeInteresse) entityManager.createQuery("select p from PontodeInteresse p where contains(p.geometry, :ponto) = true").setParameter("ponto",pontoDentro).getSingleResult();
            if (bairro != null) {
                resultado = "OK";
            } else {
                resultado = "ERRO";    
            }//if
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }//try
    }
```

POM dependencies included:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="projetoX_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/projectNameDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2):

Please check that your hibernate dialect is properly set to Postgis dialect.

Here is an example with Spring boot ***application.properties*** :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```